# How to run Script Runner with Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor

I'm using the package [Script Runner](https://atom.io/packages/script-runner) on Atom to use its user input feature. When I submit my code with `name = input("What's your name?")` I get a "NameError: name 'blank' is not defined".

It only works when I use `name = raw_input("What's your name?")`.

I understand `raw_input` is used with Python 2, so is there a way I can make it so when I run my code through the input execution (<kbd>ctrl+x</kbd>), it runs with Python 3?

It was working before, but since restarting my computer it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Most code runners will not accept user input. Instead, you need to find a [REPL package](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=repl) that suits your needs. Alternatively, a [terminal package](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=terminal) might work as well.